# phpunit anything matcher inside array

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, matcher

I have a function which returns an array of array of records after processing them. The expected return value looks something like this -

```
[
  [....]
  ['Name', 'Quantity', 'Tags', 'Price', 'Total', 'Autogenerated Value']
  [....]
  [....]
]
```

the field `Autogenerate Value` can be anything generated dynamically.

Currently I am trying to use `assertEquals` methods, but every time the auto generate value will be different. Is this there matcher something like `anything()` that I can use here.

I do not really want to write my own assertion function iterating over the expected value and assert using `assertArraySubset`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet, but you could extend PHPUnit to evaluate constraints within arrays:

- Write a custom `Comparator` implementation like this

  ```
  class ConstraintComparator extends SebastianBergmann\Comparator
  {
      public function accepts($expected, $actual)
      {
          return $expected instanceof \PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint;
      }
      public function assertEquals($expected, $actual, $delta = 0.0, $canonicalize = false, $ignoreCase = false)
      {
          $expected->evaluate($actual);
      }
  ```
- Add the comparator in your bootstrap file with:

  ```
  SebastianBergmann\Comparator\Factory::getInstance()->register(new ConstraintComparator);
  ```

Now PHPUnit should evaluate constraints instead of comparing them wherever they occur.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not really want to write my own assertion function iterating over the expected value and assert using assertArraySubset

But why not?

If you don't want a lot of assertions in your logs, you can limit your assertion method to throwing `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException` in case anything goes wrong (i.e. if the constant part of array is absent or if the last, dynamically generated element is not of expected value) with contents of the exact problem element.